# Can we read all messages of all users if we use Admin account in Exchange Server?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm writing a program using C# for reading all messages of all users if request provide the Admin account in Exchange server 2007/2010/2013. Currently, I'm using EWS Exchange service API to connecto to the Exchange server, but i can't find out the API to get list users accounts below admin account.

Can we do that using EWS Exchange service or other libraries? Any helps would be appreciate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the EWS Managed API (or EWS), impersonation is the way for one account to access multiple other accounts. It's discussed here: [Impersonation and EWS in Exchange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn722377(v=exchg.150).aspx).